# Loop through array of arrays and display each sub-array in sequence

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array which contains 3 different arrays.

```
$arrayAll = (

    0 => $array1,
    1 => $array2,
    2 => $array3
);
```

How can I loop through $arrayAll, displaying the first element of each sub-array(array1,array2,array3) on each itteration?

So, the output will be:

```
$array1[0],$array2[0],$array3[0],
$array1[1],$array2[1],$array3[1],
$array1[2],$array2[2],$array3[2]
```

and so on.. until all sublements are fetched.

EDIT:

```
$addsContent = $Adds->selectAdds(10);
$sharedArticlesContent = $SharedContent->getSharedContent($topic_selected, $filter_selected);
$blogPostsContent = $BlogPosts->getRecentBlogPostsByTopic("business");

$contentArray = array(

    $sharedArticlesContent,
    $addsContent ,
    $blogPostsContent
);


foreach($contentArray as $value)
    {
        if(count($value)>$maxLength)
        {
            $maxLength = count($value);
        }
    }

for($i=0; $i<$maxLength; $i++)
{
    foreach($contentArray as $value)
    {
        if(isset($value[$i]))
        {
            if($value==$sharedArticlesContent){
                $data = $value[$i];
                foreach($sharedArticlesContent as $data){

                    $post_id = $data['id'];
                    $uploaded_by = $data['uploaded_by'];
                    $text = $data['text'];
                    $image = $data['image'];

                    require 'template1.php';

              }
            }elseif($value==$addsContent){
                //template2
            }else{
               //template3
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are the inner arrays all of the same length?

Comment: No, they can be different lengths

Comment: I have edited my answer below to support different lengths. It can be optimized, i'll think of something else if you need an optimized script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$maxLength = 0;

foreach($arrayAll as $value)
    {
        if(count($value)>$maxLength)
        {
            $maxLength = count($value);
        }
    }

for($i=0; $i<$maxLength; $i++)
{
    foreach($arrayAll as $value)
    {
        if(isset($value[$i]))
        {
            echo $value[$i];    
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Each of array1,array2,array3 requires a different HTML template, so inside  of  foreach($arrayAll as $value){}
 I added if ($value == array1){//use template 1}elseif(//use template 2) etc.. that works well and pull the correct template however I am having difficulties with itterating over $value[$i]. It contains a number of data items, which have to be extracted. I tried foreach($value[$i] as $dataItem){}. However, that produces errors. If you see what I mean?

Comment: can u update your answer with your array? is it an associative array? object? Clarify that and I'll help you with it

Comment: Essentially i cannot just echo the $value[$i] which is an array of its own, so  I need to iterate over it somehow and foreach doesn't work on it, perhaps i have not structured it appropriately?

Comment: create an associative array like that: array('name'=>'valueofname', 'age'=>'valueOfAge'), and once you iterate over them, you can use $value[$i]['name'] for example

Comment: Edited the post based on your answer, so you can see the problem is with accessing the contents of $value[$i] and displaying it

Comment: Can you post that as a different question and link me the URL to the new question? It's a different case and I will post my answer there so that other users can make use of it as well

Comment: sure:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396095/iterating-over-array-of-arrays-and-presenting-the-results