# Iterating over array of arrays and presenting the results

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can I access the contents of $value[$i] which is an array. No luck using foreach in the form below.

The idea is to loop through $contentArray and display one item from each sub-array on every iteration.

```
$addsContent = $Adds->selectAdds(10);
$sharedArticlesContent = $SharedContent->getSharedContent($topic_selected, $filter_selected);
$blogPostsContent = $BlogPosts->getRecentBlogPostsByTopic("business");

$contentArray = array(

    $sharedArticlesContent,
    $addsContent ,
    $blogPostsContent
);


foreach($contentArray as $value)
    {
        if(count($value)>$maxLength)
        {
            $maxLength = count($value);
        }
    }

for($i=0; $i<$maxLength; $i++)
{
    foreach($contentArray as $value)
    {
        if(isset($value[$i]))
        {
            if($value==$sharedArticlesContent){
                $data = $value[$i];
                foreach($sharedArticlesContent as $data){

                    $post_id = $data['id'];
                    $uploaded_by = $data['uploaded_by'];
                    $text = $data['text'];
                    $image = $data['image'];

                    require 'template1.php';

              }
            }elseif($value==$addsContent){
                //template2
            }else{
               //template3
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with an associative array here, you can access it like that:

```
<?php

$addsContent = $Adds->selectAdds(10);
$sharedArticlesContent = $SharedContent->getSharedContent($topic_selected, $filter_selected);
$blogPostsContent = $BlogPosts->getRecentBlogPostsByTopic("business");

$contentArray = array(

$sharedArticlesContent,
$addsContent ,
$blogPostsContent
);


foreach($contentArray as $value)
{
    if(count($value)>$maxLength)
    {
        $maxLength = count($value);
    }
}

for($i=0; $i<$maxLength; $i++)
{
foreach($contentArray as $value)
{
    if(isset($value[$i]))
    {
        if($value==$sharedArticlesContent)
        {
            $post_id = $value[$i]['id'];
            $uploaded_by = $value[$i]['uploaded_by'];
            $text = $value[$i]['text'];
            $image = $value[$i]['image'];

            require 'template1.php';
        }
        elseif($value==$addsContent)
        {
            //template2
        }
        else
        {
           //template3
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but instead I used $data =  $value[$i]; It loops forever, after the 3 element. May be that is related to unequal length of the sub-arrays?

Comment: Nop, it shouldn't loop forever, it will stop after the elements have been loaded. You want to load everything correct?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `foreach`. `$data` is an associative array, you don't need to loop through it.

```
        if($value==$sharedArticlesContent){
            $data = $value[$i];
            $post_id = $data['id'];
            $uploaded_by = $data['uploaded_by'];
            $text = $data['text'];
            $image = $data['image'];

            require 'template1.php';
          }
```

Comment: Tried that. It starts well and then loops over the same $sharedArticlesContent item forever.......

Comment: I don't quite understand your data structures. Could you update the question to show what's in `$contentArray` and `SharedArticlesContent`?

Comment: And also the output you're trying to get from that. I don't understand what you mean by "display one item from each sub-array", since you have a loop from `0` to `$maxLength`.